# dynamic binding with dagger 2

Tags: android, dagger-2

I have problems migrating my Android app from `Dagger` to `Dagger2`.

I use Dagger to inject mocks at different layers during testing (unit , functional device and everything in between).

E.g. I have a `NetworkingModule` which provides a `HttpTransport` and a `ServerConnector`. For some test I just mock the http layer, for others I mock the `ServerConnector`, and other test use release classes to test integration with a real test server.

These test can be run on all build flavors (debug, release, ...).

I found only descriptions of `Dagger2` which set a single static injection configuration per build type - i.e. a release component to bind real classes and a debug component to bind one set of mocks.

I need to find a way to have the test cases replace modules in the application start up phase.

How can I achieve this? In my thoughts I always get stuck when the application triggers the building of the graph for which it has to use a Component which is the implementation of a certain interface which has static annotation of its modules???

To ask differently: Is it possible to compile multiple modules in the same build which provide the same injections? How would I then inject with the right module at run time?

Can someone please draft me a solution for my example of the `NetworkingModule`.

BTW: I make heavy use of `Espresso`, `Robolectric`, and `Mockito`.

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

I don't need build specific Components or Modules.

My modules just handle delegates which I implement and set for injecting mocks when testing. This is very cheap for release builds. And for testing I can even effort some reflection for convenience features.

Comment: Could you please provide a code example how you did it?